# How to automate a software installation on remote [windows and linux ] machine using python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

I am new to python programming, I want to automate a software installation on remote machine [windows and linux] with python 3.x.
I have tried with pywinauto to automate windows application installation on local machine and it's working fine. so I want to automate same application on remote machine.How I can do this on remote machine from running python script on local-machine? 
Can any one help on this.

Below is the code for automate application on local machine.

```
from pywinauto.application import Application as App
import time
import math
start = time.time()
app = App().start('C:\\Anaconda3-2018.12-Windows-x86_64.exe')
time.sleep(1)
ctrl = app['Anaconda3_2018.12(64-bit)_Setup']
ctrl.Next.click()
ctrl.IAgree.click()
#ctrl.print_control_identifiers()
ctrl.child_window(title="Just Me (recommended)", 
class_name="Button").click()
ctrl.Next.click()
ctrl.Edit.wait('ready').type_keys(r'C:\xx\Continuum\anaconda3', 
with_spaces = True)
ctrl.Next.click()
#ctrl.print_control_identifiers()
#ctrl.child_window(title="Add Anaconda to my &PATH environment variable", 
class_name="Button").click()
ctrl.Install.click()
#ctrl.print_control_identifiers()
ctrl.Next.wait('enabled',timeout = 600).click()
time.sleep(2)
ctrl.Skip.click()
time.sleep(1)
ctrl.Finish.wait('ready').click()
endTime = math.ceil((time.time()-start)/60)
print ('Script has taken', endTime, 'Minutes..')
```

Comment: All installers usually have command line keys for silent installation. Try `Anaconda3-2018.12-Windows-x86_64.exe /?` for more details on Windows. GUI automation is definitely an overkill here.

Comment: Anyway there is [Remote Execution Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html).

Comment: I have gone through Remote Execution Guide doc. Do I need install python and pywinauto on remote machine as well?
If this is the case, it will not helpful for me,because in my organisation I want to install applications on bulk of remote machines, so It will take much time to install python on all machines.
Is there any other way to automate application  installation  on remote machines?

Comment: It's also possible to pack your script to executable with `py2exe` and copy this executable to remote machine. But you need to write `setup.py` file for that. I would strongly recommend to read about silent options for Anaconda installer. It should be very similar to Python installer which we install silently in my company.

Comment: Thanks @VasilyRyabov on quick response, It would be really helpful for me.